# How to add a user control to the page to duplicate existing functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind

I have a page in ASP.NET that has a section for adding information.

Currently the application allows to enter only 2 owner's information.

What is the best way to enhance the application to allow to add 3 more owners.

I need to have these 3 owners to be collapsible, so the page shows only two owners and 3rd - 5th are collapsed when needed.

What I did so far is created a user control that has the same fields as tow previous owners and added this control to an asp page.

How should I proceed next?

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to the page that will insert new instances of the user control.

Comment: What I mean is should my new control's class inherit existing data or I should create a completely new class for this control and inherit System.Web.UI.UserControl?

Comment: I think you would need to make your own, there aren't any existing controls that are close to what you need right?